# RadTreeView Localization resourcekey (Telerik, Silverlight)

Tags: c#, localization, telerik, silverlight-5.0, radtreeview

I want to translate `Drag Tooltip` (Drop in, Drop after, Drop before) in `RadTreeView`. how can I do that?

I am using resource file and I successfully translated RadGridView group panel and other in built in visual structures.

I need Resource Key for Drop in, Drop after, Drop before texts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i post this on telerik forum they gave me an answer and it worked.

"The resources are not apply because the new LocalizationManager needs to be defined before the create of the application's UI. For example, you can add it just before the `InitializeComponent()` method."

```
public MainPage()
{
```

`LocalizationManager.Manager = new LocalizationManager()
    {
        ResourceManager = Resource1.ResourceManager
    };`

```
InitializeComponent();
```

.....

```
}
```

[Here is the link to that post](http://www.telerik.com/forums/drop-in-drop-after-drop-before-translation-not-working)